# Android Animation Disruption Issue

Tags: java, android, animation, countdowntimer

In a activity I have been having Rotate animation issue for the following scenario.
I have two views on my activity layout.

1. ImageView
2. TextView

I have created two Countdown-timers for the following operations:

1. CountDownTimer1: Every 1 second update the Textview text with current second using method **txtvw.setText** method.
2. CountDownTimer2: After every 60 seconds perform Image RotateAnimation.

The Rotate animation of CountDowntimer2 runs smoothly if I **disable** the setText method of CountDowntimer1. But rotate animation starts to stutter/disrupt when I **enable** the setText method of CountDowntimer1

What wrong am I doing here? Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your logcat you might get the reason for the stutter/disrupt animation. You might be getting statement like

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

This must be the reason for the stutter/disrupt animation, how you can fix it is to make sure you are not blocking the main thread.

You can try `<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>` as well. But the main issue is in the main thread getting block.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Added hardwareaccelerated to Manifest still the same issue. Note: Not seeing any Skipped frames in logcat.

Comment: post code for the corresponding  ImageView and TextView rotation please

Comment: GB_RTANIM_WHEEL_START = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat( img_wheel, View.ROTATION, 0, 360);
GB_RTANIM_WHEEL_START.setDuration(3000);
GB_RTANIM_WHEEL_START.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
GB_RTANIM_WHEEL_START.start();